# Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm)) not working in ASP.NET function when called by the JavaScript Function in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
/* javascript function */
function SubmitPayment() {
        debugger;
        var amount = parseFloat($('#txAmt').val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(',', ''));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AddFundPG.aspx/Submit",
            data: "{'amount':'" + amount + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (res) {
                debugger;
                var data = JSON.parse(res.d);
           
            },
            failure: function (res) {
                return response.d;
            }
        });
    }
```

C# function:

```
public static string Submit(string checkID, string amountStr, string noteStr)
{    
    string PGURL = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CashfreebaseURl"];
    System.Collections.Hashtable data1 = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
    ..............
    data1.Add("notifyUrl", notifyUrl.ToString());
    data1.Add("signature", signature);

    string strForm = PreparePOSTForm(PGURL, data1);
    HttpContext.Current.Session["TransData"] = data1;

    //Page page1 = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
    Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm));
}
```

`Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm));` is not working when calling from Javascript function; when I called this function from C#, then it's working fine.

Comment: not working means?

Comment: What are you trying to do? That code would only work in WebForms, which is rendered entirely on the server. Unless you add JavaScript code to reload the entire page or modify an entire part of it, the HTML won't change. That's the whole reason WebForms was abandoned and replaced by ASP.NET MVC and Razor Pages

Comment: The JS code expects a JSON response with `var data = JSON.parse(res.d);`, not an updated page.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you using WebForms at all if you want to make AJAX calls and dynamically update the UI?

Comment: As said, what's not working? Do you get an error message or....?

Answer (score 0):

### Change data content and try again.

data: "{'amountStr':'" + amount + "'}",

Comment: just do as you answered, but not working... issue at Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm)); not redirect to URL.

Comment: You can't modify client-side HTML from WebForms server-side code